# C++ Regex "Parenthesis is not closed." Error

Tags: c++, regex

In a game I'm making, I'm using a Regex expression to be able to parse in level data from a file. To test this, I'm trying to use the Regex expression `(?<=(LEVEL_TYPE:\s))(\w+|[+-]*\d+)` to try and get the level type data in the file which is formatted like `LEVEL_TYPE: UNDERWATER`

This is my code:

```
   std::string RegexPattern("(?<=(LEVEL_TYPE:\\s))(\\w+|[+-]*\\d+)");
   std::string target = "LEVEL_TYPE: UNDERWATER";
   std::regex reg(RegexPattern);
```

Without even using the regex_match method, the program throws an error why I try to run the code. When I try to run it, it throws the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  Parenthesis is not closed.
```

I'm trying to compile on MinGW on Windows, GCC version 6.3.0

Comment: Sometimes parsing a string using a grammar is simpler than using a Regex.

Comment: '))' is maybe your problem, why two closes?

Comment: @pm100 There's 2 opening parenthesis

Comment: `(?<=` is not valid syntax, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript#Assertions.

Comment: @user17732522 well if I can't use a positive lookbehind then how am I supposed to be able to do this? I can't think of any possible way to do it.

Comment: @Gold87 not inside the string there isnt

Comment: @Gold87 I'll let someone more familiar with regex answer what the correct alternative to the lookbehind is, but aside from that `boost::regex` probably supports it. `std::regex` is known to have problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a reason for the lookbehind. Isn't this enough?

```
std::string RegexPattern("(LEVEL_TYPE:\\s)(\\w+|[+-]*\\d+)");
```

Comment: Or `"LEVEL_TYPE:\\s(\\w+|[+-]*\\d+)"` if you don't want the first part to be captured.